How to SUM all values from a MONEY column with the same DATE into one row for that date
I have tables I need to get combined (SUM of) daily production values on one row for each date to calculate total production for that department for each unique date. My t-SQL code below returns separate rows, as shown in the results that I have pasted below the query.
USE CPR
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CPR_TotalDailyHygieneProd1845] (
    [HygienistReportDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [TotalDailyHygieneProd] [MONEY] NULL)
Insert INTO dbo.CPR_TotalDailyHygieneProd1845 (
    HygienistReportDate,
    TotalDailyHygieneProd)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(dbo.tHygienistStats.ReportDate AS DATE),
    SUM(dbo.tHygienistStats.DailyHygieneProd) AS TotalDailyHygieneProd
FROM dbo.tHygienistStats
WHERE dbo.tHygienistStats.PracticeID = '1845'
    GROUP BY 
    dbo.tHygienistStats.ReportDate,
    dbo.tHygienistStats.DailyHygieneProd
GO

HygienistReportDate TotalDailyHygieneProd
2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 549.00
2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 1291.00
2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 1351.00
2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 1501.00
2024-07-18 00:00:00.000 909.00
2024-07-18 00:00:00.000 1092.00
2024-07-18 00:00:00.000 1228.00
2024-07-18 00:00:00.000 1342.00
2024-07-18 00:00:00.000 1518.00
2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 0.00
2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 953.00
2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 1223.00
2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 1431.00
2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 1783.00

Please see my examples that I have pasted above.

Solved by own issue, and I hope it can help someone else. I removed dbo.tHygienistStats.DailyHygieneProd from the GROUP BY clause.
